# Title being displayed both in browser's bar and in body in Django

Tags: python, django, title

I am following the book "Django By Example" and I tried to implement  tags. I expect the title to be shown only on the browser's title bar. However, the text inside   is being displayed both on the browser's title bar **but also on the webpage content**.
[image]

If I look at the page source, of that screenshot, it looks like this:

```
    </nav>
    

            
 Title goes here 

<div class="container">
```

And here is how the first lines of my base.html look like:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
```

And here is the template of the page shown in the screenshot:

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}
    {% block title %} Title goes here {% endblock %}
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
    
        <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-2 left  top">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="">
              Here is some content.
          </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% block sidebar %} {% include 'sidebar.html' %} {% endblock sidebar %}
      </div>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Do you know how to get rid of the tile being displayed on the page body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact your block *title* is also in the block *content* might be the reason, just put it outside.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 

{% block title %} 
    Title goes here 
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
    
        <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-2 left  top">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="">
              Here is some content.
          </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% block sidebar %} {% include 'sidebar.html' %} {% endblock sidebar %}
      </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!